# How is a contract defined by an interface without implementing all functions?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

In the following code the "MainContract" contract is constructed by passing the address of a "MyInterface" Object. I'm able to construct a "MainContract" contract by by passing the address of a "ContractInherits" contract. How is this possible when "ContractInherits" doesn't implement the "randomFunction()" function?
Is ContractInherits actually inheriting from MyInterface?

```js
pragma solidity 0.8.19;

interface MyInterface{
    function changeVariable() external;
    function randomFunction() external;
}

contract ContractInherits {
    uint256 public a_variable;

    function changeVariable() public {
        a_variable = a_variable++;
    }  
}

contract MainContract {
    MyInterface public immutable ContractInherits;

    constructor(MyInterface _ContractInherits) {
        ContractInherits = _ContractInherits;
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: This isn't Python.

Comment: @itprorh66 How much more information can I provide? I asked a specific question and provided the entire file of code.

Comment: **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.   While it is beneficial to show your work effort, it is counter productive to dump all code.  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: @itprorh66 Got it. I've edited the question to be more concise.

Comment: @Goober117 in this instance you'll run into a runtime error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll demo an example of [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76292337/how-is-a-contract-defined-by-an-interface-without-implementing-all-functions#comment134555941_76292337), that you'll get a runtime error.

Here is your original code, with a couple of modifications:

- Changed the `ContractInherits` variable name within `MainContract` to `instanceOfContractInherits` to clarify what it really is, plus avoid variable shadowing.
- Added a `doStuff()` function for the runtime error will be produced.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.19;

interface MyInterface{
    function changeVariable() external;
    function randomFunction() external;
}

contract ContractInherits {
    uint256 public a_variable;

    function changeVariable() public {
        a_variable = a_variable++;
    }  
}

contract MainContract {
    MyInterface public immutable instanceOfContractInherits;

    constructor(MyInterface _ContractInherits) {
        instanceOfContractInherits = _ContractInherits;
    }

    function doStuff() public {
        instanceOfContractInherits.changeVariable();
        instanceOfContractInherits.randomFunction();
    }
}
```

Then I've done the following in Remix:

(1) Deploy `ContractInherits`

(2) Copy its deployed address

(3) Deploy `MainContract`, passing in the just copied address into its constructor

(4) Invoke the `instanceOfContractInherits` accessor function

At this point, the "Deployed Contracts" section looks like this:

[image: deployed-contracts-remix]

Now for the runtime error as promised:

(5) Invoke the `doStuff` transaction function

(6) Observe the transaction status of `revert` in the logs

```
transact to MainContract.doStuff errored: VM error: revert.

revert
```

(7) Expand the lines in the logs that started with `[vm]` to the the reason, which is:

```
status  false Transaction mined but execution failed
```

[image: transaction-error]

---

So, why does this happen?

The solidity compiler `solc` does not (and cannot) know
what the interface is at compile time, because

1. You are only passing in the deployed address for the implementation of that interface at run time (the constructor argument).
2. Even if the above were not true (let's say you hardcoded the address instead of accepting it as a constructor argument), it still would not know, because

- (a) `solc` does not access the network during compilation,
- (b) `solc` cannot infer ABI from bytecode (reverse engineering is not one of the things it does), and
- (c) `solc` should produce bytecode that is agnostic to which EVM-compatible network it is deployed to (e.g. it could be deployed to another network where the address referenced does indeed have a working implementation for this interface)

Comment: Good explanation. Still pretty new to Solidity, thanks for the help!